# passing argument 2 of ‘strstr’ makes pointer from integer without a cast?

Tags: c, pointers, strstr

what does this warning mean? I read some other posts about a similar question, but I'm still not understanding how to go about solving it.

```
# define EOT_CHAR '\04'
char buffer[MAXLINE];

            if ( strstr( buffer, EOT_CHAR ) != NULL )
            {
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

`strstr` is used to locate a substring and requires a pointer to a string as its second argument. To locate a character use `strchr` function.

Comment: Exactly. EOT_CHAR is a character, which is a special case of an integer in the C language. The strstr() function takes two pointers to characters, so the compiler was complaining that the second argument, which in you case was an integer, was being converted to a pointer.